# How to swap out single elements between two lists when they are greater then each other

Tags: python

I have two lists where I want to control the first element of both lists and when the element of the second list is smaller swap them.

This is my code for that:

```
if yListe[0] < xListe[0]:
    xListe[0], yListe[0] = yListe[0], xListe[0]
if yListe[1] < xListe[1]:
    xListe, yListe = yListe , xListe
```

The elements inside these lists are coordinates on the x and y axes

But I am getting the following error:
`'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

I tried to also do this:

```
for x1, y2 in zip(xListe, yListe):
    if y2 < x1:
        xListe[x1], yListe[y2] = y2, x1
```

But the same error. How can I fix this?

SAMPLE DATA:
These are values on choose x and y axis

```
List1 = [123,120]
List2 = [80,150]
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
for i, (x1, y2) in enumerate(zip(xListe, yListe)):
    if y2 < x1:
        xListe[i], yListe[i] = y2, x1
```

UPDATED Sample data LATEST:

```
List1 = [123,120]
List2 = [80,150]
```

In this case, we are checking if 80 is smaller than 123, and if yes we swap these two values so 80 and 123, then we are checking 150 and 120 but because 150 is greater we are not doing anything. I know the code to swap the complete list but what I want to do is swap out single elements

Comment: IDK about your first example, but the second makes sense, because zip creates a tuple of 2 iterables, and tuples of course are immutable. Can you give some sample data to replicate with?

Comment: added sample data

Comment: What the output look like?  [80, 120], [90, 123]?

Comment: Yes but I changed the sample because it was a bit wrong. With the new data only the 80 and 90 has to be swapped

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - let's say `list1=[123,120]` and `list2=[80,90]` then we swap 123 and 80 as 80<123 and we get: `list1=[80,120]`, `list2=[123,90]` then what do we compare? 80 to 90? 120 to 90? 120 to 123?

Comment: Updated my questions and explained it a bit better

Answer (score 0):

```
In [54]: xList = [1,2,3,4]

In [55]: yList = [1,1,4,5]

In [56]: for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(xList, yList)):
    ...:     if y<x:
    ...:         xList[i], yList[i] = y,x
    ...:

In [57]: xList
Out[57]: [1, 1, 3, 4]

In [58]: yList
Out[58]: [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but now I am getting the following error: cannot unpack non-iterable int object I a updating my question

Comment: I had not added enumerate, but now added enumerate and again getting this error: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @natyus: I think your `xListe` and `yListe` are tuples (eg: `(1,2,3)`) rather than lists (eg: `[1,2,3]`). That would cause the error you see

Comment: Yes that's how they look, I am still new to python sorry. How can I achieve what I want with tupples? This is for example one tipple: (271, 528)

Comment: Tuples are meant to be immutable. So you cannot change individual components of them. You'll need to use lists instead

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Code:

```
xList = [123, 120]
yList = [80, 90]

for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(xList, yList)):
    if y<x:
       xList[i], yList[i] = y,x
    print(xList[i], yList[i])
```

Output:

```
80 123
90 120
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Are you on macOS, etc. It worked for me Python 3.12.0a1

Comment: I am on macOs but I don't have a list but a tuple and that was my error. Do you know how to swap elements inside tuples? I am still new to python

Comment: What's  your Python version?